# How to validate register and login form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, validation

I have a register and login form in my site. I want the user to stay logged in, when they complete the register form and click register or when they click login if they are already registered, but not logged in.

I also want to be able to switch views when user is logged in through a button in the nav bar that has their username. When the user is not logged in, there will be a login/register button in the nav bar.

This is what I have so far.

I will be very grateful to all who respond to my inquiry. Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
//login form

<section class="module">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 mb-sm-40">
            <h4 class="font-alt">Login</h4>
            <hr class="divider-w mb-10">
            <form class="form" name="loginForm" onSubmit="validateForm();" action="index_shop.html" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="username" name="usr" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="password" name="pwd" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-round btn-b" type="submit" value="login">Login</button>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group"><a href="">Forgot Password?</a></div>
            </form>
          </div>    

 //register form
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <h4 class="font-alt">Register</h4>
            <hr class="divider-w mb-10">
            <form class="form" name="regForm" onsubmit="return Validate();" action="index_shop.html" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="Email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                <div id="email_error"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="RegUser" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                <div id="name_error"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="RegPass" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="confirmPass" type="password" name="confirmPass" placeholder="Re-enter Password"/>
                <div id="password_error"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-round btn-b" type="submit" value="register">Register</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

JavaScript

```
//Login validatation

 function validateForm() {
            var user = document.loginForm.usr.value;
            var pass = document.loginForm.pwd.value;
            var username = "username";
            var password = "password";
            if ((user == username) && (pass == password)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
                return false;
            }
        }
//registerValidation

        var email = document.forms['regForm']['email'];
        var username = document.forms['regForm']['username'];
        var password = document.forms['regForm']['password'];
        var password_confirm = document.forms['regForm']['confirmPass'];

        var name_error = document.getElementById('name_error');
        var email_error = document.getElementById('email_error');
        var password_error = document.getElementById('password_error');

        username.addEventListener('blur', nameVerify, true);
        email.addEventListener('blur', emailVerify, true);
        password.addEventListener('blur', passwordVerify, true);

        function Validate() {
            // validate email
            if (email.value == "") {
                email.style.border = "1px solid red";
                document.getElementById('Email').style.color = "red";
                email_error.textContent = "Email is required";
                email.focus();
                return false;
            }
            // validate username
            if (username.value == "") {
                username.style.border = "1px solid red";
                document.getElementById('RegUser').style.color = "red";
                name_error.textContent = "Username is required";
                username.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (username.value.length < 3) {
                username.style.border = "1px solid red";
                document.getElementById('RegUser').style.color = "red";
                name_error.textContent = "Username must be at least 3 characters";
                username.focus();
                return false;
            }
            // validate password
            if (password.value == "") {
                password.style.border = "1px solid red";
                document.getElementById('RegPass').style.color = "red";
                password_confirm.style.border = "1px solid red";
                password_error.textContent = "Password is required";
                password.focus();
                return false;
            }
            // check if the two passwords match
            if (password.value != confirmPass.value) {
                password.style.border = "1px solid red";
                document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "red";
                password_confirm.style.border = "1px solid red";
                password_error.innerHTML = "The two passwords do not match";
                return false;
            }
        }
        // event handler functions
        function nameVerify() {
            if (username.value != "") {
                username.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
                document.getElementById('RegUser').style.color = "#5e6e66";
                name_error.innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
        function emailVerify() {
            if (email.value != "") {
                email.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
                document.getElementById('Email').style.color = "#5e6e66";
                email_error.innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
        function passwordVerify() {
            if (password.value != "") {
                password.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
                document.getElementById('RegPass').style.color = "#5e6e66";
                document.getElementById('confirmPass').style.color = "#5e6e66";
                password_error.innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
            if (password.value === password_confirm.value) {
                password.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
                document.getElementById('confirmPass').style.color = "#5e6e66";
                password_error.innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Initial comment: Assuming a login implies some sort of authentication, and considering any authentication would require at least some form of security in order to pass a test to be called one, you pretty much only have an extended validation, and not a login. It's great in the spirit of learning, but I feel obliged to point out that this should not be used for anything but learning, and that the response below is for perspective, and not really anything else*

With that said, what you seem to be looking for is simply some way of persisting the fact that a user has entered the correct values into your forms, to make sure that if they leave and come back, or reload, you can still treat them as proper inputters.

I'd say the most common/simple ways of persisting data in JavaScript is through cookies or LocalStorage. LocalStorage does come with some issues, but lets leave that out for now. To store data, LocalStorage takes a key and a value, and stores that value in association with that key in the browser of the user on your page. Using the key, we can later retrieve it.

So, basically, a good starting point is to create a function that is able to persist data, and one that is able to retrieve data.

We can create something like:

```
// Really just an abstraction of localStorage.setItem, it'll come in handy 
function storeData(storageKey, myValueToStore) {
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, myValueToStore);
}

// Really just an abstraction of localStorage.getItem, it'll come in handy
function getData(storageKey) {
    localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
}
```

With these 2 functions available, we can now, as a very, very, very, very simple example, store the username for someone who logs in or registers, and then later check if there is any username available. Thus, our persistence of the "authentication" depends on whether the user has ever retrieved a proper username.

It would look something like this:

```
 function validateForm() {
      var user = document.loginForm.usr.value;
      var pass = document.loginForm.pwd.value;
      var username = "username";
      var password = "password";
      if ((user == username) && (pass == password)) {


          // User entered the correct input, lets store it so that we later can 
          // ensure that he has done so
          storeData("validatedUserName", user); // Store the user with key "validatedUserName"


          return true;
      }
      else {
          alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Now, you can later check if any such data exists, and use that to "verify" the user:

```
// In some sort of start up or initially running script:
var previouslyEnteredUserName = getData("validatedUserName");

// If we didn't find any value, our variable will be null, so we can use that
// to check for "login"
if (previouslyEnteredUserName !== null) {
    alert("Hello " + previouslyEnteredUserName + ", welcome back!");
}
else {
     alert("Hey, you have never logged in to this system! I don't have any username stored for you in my LocalStorage!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'll start by saying that any authentication shouldn't be handled by client side javascript. It should be validated server-side and checked each time the user navigates to a "secure" page. That said, here's how I would do what you're attempting.**

**1.** Store login successful information in a session cookie. You can use this lightweight plugin to do so. 
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

**2.** Set a cookie called "sessionAuth" and its value to "true" when the user submits the login form and you validate their information and it's correct. You can check this on each page load like so. (I'm writing this in jQuery, it's just easier, but use Plain JS if you want)

```js
var userName = "User's Name";

if ( Cookies.get("sessionAuth") && Cookies.get('sessionAuth') == "true" ) {
 //User is logged in
 $(".login-btn").attr("href","/account").text(userName);
}
else {
 //User is not logged in, do things here
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Help</a>
  <a class="login-btn" href="/login">Login</a>
</nav>
```

**That's how I'd do it, but I'd never do it client side. Anyone can see your code and it's very insecure. I can't stress this enough!**

Comment: Right, javascript can be modified and inspected by the user, so that is one reason why this is insecure.